# Multiple string replacement

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

All I want is to transform **'1.234,56'** into **'1,234.56'**...

I read about using **array**(s) as str_replace parameter, so I did this:

```
$value = '1.234,56';
$replacer1 = ',';
$replacer2 = '.';
echo \str_replace(array($replacer1, $replacer2), array($replacer2,$replacer1), $value);
//Prints '1,234,56' instead of '1,234.56'
```

The input and it's replacers are variable and it's not necessarily'll be used only for numbers.

Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: there are price\number format specify functions which you should check out first

Comment: This reads a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you trying to achieve, simply swapping occurrences of a particular character with another?

Comment: Yes, Alex, thats exactly what I'm trying, without usin a third variable or auxiliary replacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.i used [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for this

```
<?php

$number = "1.234,56";

$number = str_replace(array('.',','), array('','.'), $number);

echo number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
```

You can also use [money_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function.Note that it won't work on windows.

Here is another method.

```
<?php

$str = "1.234,56";

$rp1 = '.';
$rp2 = ',';

//you might want to create a function for this.
if(false===strpos($str, '@')){

$str = str_replace($rp1, '@', $str);
$str = str_replace($rp2, $rp1, $str);
$str = str_replace('@', $rp2, $str);

}

echo $str;
```

You can also use a unique string like `#!MYSEP!#`

Comment: Is there a way to guarantee that the '@' replacer is not present in $str?